# How to calculate time difference between different rows based off criteria/conditions in R

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, calculation

I have the following data frame and I am looking to create a variable that calculates the amount of days between the current `ADMITDATE` from the previous `DISCHARGE DATE` only for duplicates or when the `ID`s are equal

```
ID  ADMITDATE   DISCHARGE DATE  
1   5/24/2020   5/27/2020   
1   5/30/2020   6/15/2020   
2   3/9/2010    4/5/2020    
3   2/7/2020    3/7/2020    
4   5/15/2020   5/16/2020   
4   5/20/2020   5/25/2020   
4   5/30/2020   6/15/2020   
5   7/8/2020    7/20/2020   
6   1/20/2020   1/22/2020   
6   1/28/2020   2/5/2020
```

So I want the output to look like below.

```
ID    ADMITDATE     DISCHARGE DATE  DAYDIFF

1   5/24/2020   5/27/2020   NULL

1   5/30/2020   6/15/2020   3

2   3/9/2010    4/5/2020    NULL

3   2/7/2020    3/7/2020    NULL

4   5/15/2020   5/16/2020   NULL

4   5/20/2020   5/25/2020   4

4   5/30/2020   6/15/2020   5

5   7/8/2020    7/20/2020   NULL

6   1/20/2020   1/22/2020   NULL

6   1/28/2020   2/5/2020    6
```

Any tips on how to write the code for this in R?

The code i currently have is

```
df$DAYDIFF <- [df$ID==lag(ID)] <- as.Date(as.character(test$ADMITDATE), format="%m/%d/%Y")-
  lag(as.Date(as.character(test$DISCHARGEDATE), format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a dataframe called `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
     mutate(ADMITDATE = mdy(ADMITDATE),
            DISCHARGEDATE = mdy(DISCHARGEDATE)) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(DAYDIFF = ADMITDATE - lag(DISCHARGEDATE, 1))
```

The `mutate` call converts your columns to date formats using lubridate to specify the format as month-day-year. We then `group_by` the `ID` values, before calculating the difference between the current `ADMITDATE`and the previous `DISCHARGEDATE` (using `lag()`)

Comment: Thank you @stlba